# How to deploy NestJS services with graphql, serverless lambda in the Localstack?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, nestjs, serverless

## Solution

*I found the solution, thanks for your time. StackOverflow doesn't let me answer me.    >:(*

## Description

> I would like to know what kind of configuration I need to perform to deploy a lambda Localstack of an application in NesJS that has Graphql, not RestApi. This is my configuration.

1. Is correct this configuration?
2. How can I get the fake link to access the playground across lambda Localstack?

## Implementation

### Configuration the nestJS lambda function project

```
import { ValidationPipe } from '@nestjs/common';
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { ExpressAdapter } from '@nestjs/platform-express';
import serverlessExpress from '@vendia/serverless-express';
import { APIGatewayProxyHandler, Handler } from 'aws-lambda';
import express from 'express';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

let cachedServer: Handler;

const bootstrapServer = async (): Promise<Handler> => {
  const expressApp = express();
  const app = await NestFactory.create(
    AppModule,
    new ExpressAdapter(expressApp),
  );
  app.useGlobalPipes(new ValidationPipe());
  app.enableCors();
  await app.init();
  return serverlessExpress({
    app: expressApp,
  });
};

export const handler: APIGatewayProxyHandler = async (
  event,
  context,
  callback,
) => {
  if (!cachedServer) {
    cachedServer = await bootstrapServer();
  }
  return cachedServer(event, context, callback);
};
```

### Serverless.yml Configuration

```yaml
service: test

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs14.x
  stage: ''
  # profile: local # Config your AWS Profile
  environment: # Service wide environment variables
    NODE_ENV: local
    GLOBAL_PREFIX: graphql
    PORT: 4000

plugins:
#  - serverless-plugin-typescript
#  - serverless-plugin-optimize
#  - serverless-offline
 - serverless-localstack

custom:
  localstack:
    debug: true
    stages:
     - local
     - dev
    endpointFile: localstack_endpoints.json
    individually: true
  # serverless-offline:
  #   httpPort: 3000
    
functions:
 main:
   handler: dis/index.handler

#  local:
#    handler: dist/main.handler
#    events:
#      - http:
#           path: /
#           method: any
#           cors: true
```

### Docker Compose Localstack

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services: 
  localstack:
    image: localstack/localstack:latest
    environment: 
      - AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
      - EDGE_PORT=4566
      - SERVICES=lambda,s3,cloudformation,sts
    ports: 
      - '4566-4597:4566-4597'
    volumes: 
      - "${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/localstack:/tmp/localstack"
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
```

### Services

```json
{
    "CloudFormation" : "http://localhost:4566",
    "CloudWatch" : "http://localhost:4566",
    "Lambda" : "http://localhost:4566",
    "S3" : "http://localhost:4566"
}
```

### Commands

> serverless deploy --stage local
> [When executing this command I get this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6OXK.png)

> serverless info --stage local
> [When executing this command I get this information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loOvH.png)

> serverless invoke local -f main -l
> [When executing this command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ufnm0.png)

Comment: So, what about the current configuration doesn't work? Because I can't tell from just the code that's here. Are you getting any errors during deploy? During startup? What about this isn't enough?

Comment: Yes, I get an error, but I think it's because I don't know how to configure it.
My question is, how should I configure it? If that configuration is correct or not?
I'm going to up the error. Appreciate your answer.

Comment: Ready I upload a few pictures.

Comment: Looks like from that last image it can't find your `dist/index` file. I don't really have much experience with lambda, so no clue what it's looking for here. Might be missing a build step somewhere?

Comment: I try to change the path for `src/index` and well, send the same error. But thanks for giving me ideas. @JayMcDoniel  `Might be missing a build step somewhere?`, that is the point I don't know, hehe.

Comment: `I think I already found the solution, stack overflow does not allow me to answer my own question, so if you need help with this do not hesitate to tell me.`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but probably you have a typo here at Serverless.yml:

```
handler: dis/index.handler
```

Comment: I already found the solution, stack overflow does not allow me to answer my own question, so if you need help with this do not hesitate to tell me. thanks